# Joining zinc components

Tags: casting

I have a zinc lock box that looks like this:

[image]

where there's a top and a bottom part. Notice that there're two interesting features (circled in red):

[image]

After cutting it up slightly:
[image]
[image]

The section view (of the right feature) looks like the following:

[image]

And the part circled in blue previously looks like:

[image]

Are those features results of some staking operation? If so, is it common for staking to produce such clean, squarish dents (red arrow) even on the lower part? My guess is that these might be designed for holding the two parts together.

**UPDATE**

I've now cut another piece off to hopefully aid better understanding:

[image]

[image]

The features highlighted by red arrows don't seem to be regular shapes. The corners of the deformations in the upper component seem to have very small radii, but the features in the lower component that "bite" into the upper component look quite rough. Could this mean that the dents in the upper part were part of the cast and not deformations created by staking into the lower part?

Comment: This looks like a casting. Possibly the dents were originally "risers" or "feeders" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riser_(casting) which ensure that the mould remains completely filled as the molten metal cools and contracts. The excess material is  cut off from the finished part. If they will be invisible when the part is being used, there is no particular reason to cut them off "neatly".

Comment: @alephzero I've cut another piece off now. It looks like there's a feature in the lower part that might be designed to "bite" into upper part. Please see update.